# Trying to update fields in Data Extension with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I realize this might a very basic question but I am completely new to SSJS so thanks for the understanding.

In Marketing Cloud I am trying run SSJS script in order to update a field in a data extension. Using the available documentation I have put together the following:

```
<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="Post" executioncontextname=test>

var TestDE = DataExtension.Init("TEST_DataExtension");
TestDE.Rows.Update({"AccountId":"Test_account"}, ["ContactId"],
["0032405071zljdyAAA"]);

</script>
```

The syntax seems to be correct and I can run the query via automation studio with no errors but the data extension is not getting updated the way I want it. In other words, field `AccountId` in `TEST_DataExtension` is not being changed to `"Test_Account"` for user with `ContactId` of `0032405071zljdyAAA`.

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: easiest way to debug the script activities is to run it inside a landing page or cloud page.  Outside of that, if you are more comfortable in AMPScript, you can have the AMPScript stored in a content area (classic only) and just have the SSJS call this content block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declaration of [Server-Side JavaScript Block](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/) is incorrect and you have not included the `SSJS libraries` in your SSJS code.

```
<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="get">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1");

var TestDE = DataExtension.Init("TEST_DataExtension");
var result = TestDE.Rows.Update({"AccountId":"Test_account"}, ["ContactId"],["0032405071zljdyAAA"]);

Write('<b>Output:</b>'+result);
</script>
```

**Output:** 1

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. Really appreciate the help

Comment: Good to know! Mark my answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to debug SSJS in an Activity, you can use try/catch to grab the error and write it to a data extension:

```
<script runat = server language = "JavaScript">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
try {
    undefinedfunction();
    writeErrorLog("process done");
}
catch (e) {
    var result = e.name + ": " + e.message;
    writeErrorLog(result);
}

function writeErrorLog(msg) {
    var errorLogDE = DataExtension.Init("ENT.errorlog");
    errorLogDE.Rows.Add({message:msg});
}
</script>
```

I made a shared data extension with a message column of text that I can write to from anywhere in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting it into a Cloud page or email and see what errors/status you get using 
`Write(YOURVARIABLEHERE)`.
My Guess at first glance is that it may be something to do with the JSON :D
Doug